# display data in a table format using jqgrid

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jqgrid

Can anyone tell me how to fetch data from a controller returning data of type hashmap into jqgrid?

This is what i have tried. Its entering into a infinite lop

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datatable").jqGrid({
        url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employees",
        cache: false,
        colNames:["id","name","age","salary","address","laptop"],
        colModel:[
                    {name:"id",index:"id", width:60},
                    {name:"name",index:"name", width:90},
                    {name:"age",index:"age", width:100},
                    {name:"salary",index:"salary", width:80, align:"right"},
                    {name:"address",index:"address", width:80, 
align:"right"},     
                    {name:"laptop",index:"laptop", width:80,align:"right"}      
                ],

            mtype: "GET",
            rownumbers: true,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            gridview: true,
            caption: "Hashmap Data"
    });
});
```

Controller Part

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView listEmployees() {
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   model.put("employees",  
  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
  for (Entry<String, Object> entry : model.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey().toString();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("hello   key, " + key + " value " + value);
       }
  return new ModelAndView("employeesList", model);
 }
```

example:
employees value [1 ram 22 12234 usa yes, 6 abc  25 23889 xyz, yes]

Please someone help me in solving this.
its giving parse error: invalid xml message

Comment: Please show us the example data of that AJAX call.

Comment: value [1 ram 22 12234 usa yes, 6 abc 25 23889 xyz, yes]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are missing on `datatype` key in the jqgrid options

Check what does your url `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employees` returns? and specify the same data type in another option `datatype`

According to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) the default value of `datatype` is `xml`.

Try changing it to `json`

Comment: Is there any possibility of doing it without converting to json?

Comment: this is what the documentation says that you can give in datatype:

Defines in what format to expect the data that fills the grid. Valid options are xml (we expect data in xml format), xmlstring (we expect xml data as string), json (we expect data in JSON format), jsonstring (we expect JSON data as a string), local (we expect data defined at client side (array data)), javascript (we expect javascript as data), function (custom defined function for retrieving data), or clientSide to manually load data via the data array.

Comment: I have tried giving the datatype as both xml as well as local.

Comment: But its displaying a table with no data.

Comment: what does your ajax call returns exactly ? comment it here

Comment: i m trying to return hashmap from controller. But i don't know how access it in jqgrid.

Comment: Can you copy and paste your returned hashmap here ?